# How would you edit a question containing an image, if the link has already expired or is broken?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

[Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668291/download-whole-folder-from-sourceforge)

I came across a question where the user inserted a link to an image instead of inserting an image directly, due to low reputation.

I was about to edit the question by replacing the link with the image, but the link was on `http://`, in which SE doesn't allow anymore.  I tried replacing it with `https://`, but it only displayed the alternate text, so it turns out that the link is broken.  I tried visiting the link to the image, but it can't be reached.  I also tried visiting the website itself, but still got no luck.

I don't know how should I edit this.  I don't know if I should put a sign or a text saying that the link is broken, or has already expired.

I'm thinking if I should put a blockquote below, like this:

> Note from an editor: link is broken, or has already expired.

Or, just simply adding a text beside the link, like this:

Link: http://example.com/example.jpg (Link is broken, or has already expired)

What do you think is the best way to do that?

---

Also, I don't know about this, but I think the question should be migrated to another Q&A site here on SE, because I don't think it is a question for coding or programming.

Comment: Haven't visited the question, but I would remove the link altogether. If the question doesn't make sense without that information, flag/vote to close. Doubly so if the question was closable even if the link was not broken.